# What does "parse junctions" mean when copying all files to another drive?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-backup, disk-cloning, volume-shadow-copy

The free program Shadow Copy is supposed to copy all files from one drive to another, including system and hidden files, so the destination will also be bootable if the source was.

There is an option called "parse junctions."  What does that mean?  The software is by Runtime Software, and they don't say what that does in their documentation.  Google fails to answer it either.

Comment: It appears than junctions only exist on linux systems and Windows 2000 and newer NTFS formatted drives (not an XP NTFS drive).  As I'm using this on an old XP laptop, I don't think it's applicable.  I hope someone more knowledgeable can confirm.

Comment: Windows XP is newer than Windows 2000 and it supports junctions. I'm not aware of any junctions that would be created by default, though. Vista and newer have some.

Answer (score 0):

Parse junctions means that the symlinks are analyzed, if any.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Info from a German thread: http://board.gulli.com/thread/1628648-shadow-copy-parse-junctions/ ([machine translated version](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fboard.gulli.com%2Fthread%2F1628648-shadow-copy-parse-junctions%2F&edit-text=&act=url))